# Does There Exist an M-Proof Shorter than Twenty-Lines of the Rule of Antecedent Commutation?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages, axioms

Peter Smith writes in his [Type of Proof System](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/ProofSystems.pdf)

"I  take  it  that  neither  of  those  proofs  is  wonderfully  obvious  or  natural.  For  another example, consider (P -> (Q -> R)) $\vdash$$_M$
(Q -> (P -> R)). Again, that's an intuitively ob-vious validity, and can be checked by a quick tree proof (do it!). But the shortest known m-proof has twenty-one lines..."

The M-system has axiom schema:

Ax1. (A -> (B -> A))

Ax2. ((A -> (B -> C)) -> ((A -> B) -> (A -> C)))

Ax3. (($\lnot$ B -> $\lnot$A) -> (A -> B))

The only rule of inference is formal modus ponens; from A and (A -> C) infer C.

Can (P -> (Q -> R)) $\vdash$$_M$ (Q -> (P -> R)) get proven in less than twenty-one lines?

Comment: Assume condensed detachment as the only rule of inference for the following.  The system {CCaCbcCCabCac, CaCba} has 2 step, level 2 proof of Caa.  {CCaCbcCCabCac, CaCba, CpCqr} has a 4 step, level 4  proof of CqCpr.  {CCaCbcCCabCac, CaCba, Cpq, Cqr} has a 3 step, level 3 proof of Cpr.

Comment: The system {CaCba, CCaCbcCCabCac, CCNaNbCba, CNCpNqp} has a 10 step, level 10 proof of the wff p also!  At least, the above hold via some reasoning and use of OTTER.  In the maximal case, a condensed detachment proof of 1 step corresponds to a 3 step substitution and detachment proof of the same wff.  So, the 10 step hyper-resolution proof of OTTER implying a 10 step condensed proof entails that a 31 step proof of the wff p can get written for the substitution and detachment system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we rewrite the definition of well-formed formula of M in Polish notation.  Then, it follows that the correlates of the above axiom schema can get written as the following:

```
                   level
Ax1 CaCba            0
Ax2 CCaCbcCCabCac    0
Ax3 CCNbNaCba        0
```

Formal modus ponens in Smith's system L corresponds to C-detachment; from Cac and a, we may infer c.

The question then corresponds to asking:

"Given CpCqr as a premiss in the above system in Polish notation, can we derive CqCpr in less than twenty-one lines?"

Consider the following:

```
                                                    level
premiss                      1 CpCqr                  0
Ax2 a/p, b/q, c/r            2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr          1
2 * C1-3                     3 CCpqCpr                2
Ax1 a/CCpqCpr, b/q           4 CCCpqCprCqCCpqCpr      1
4 * C3-5                     5 CqCCpqCpr              3
Ax2 a/q, b/Cpq, c/Cpr        6 CCqCCpqCprCCqCpqCqCpr  1
6 * C5-7                     7 CCqCpqCqCpr            4
Ax1 a/q, b/p                 8 CqCpq                  1
7 * C8-9                     9 CqCpr                  5
```

Consequently, given CpCqr as a premiss, CqCpr can get derived in nine steps.  Nine is less than twenty-one.  Therefore, (P -> (Q -> R)) ⊢$_M$ (Q -> (P -> R) can get proven in less than twenty-one steps.

Existence of such a proof:

```
(a -> (b -> a))
((a -> (b -> c)) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c)))
(p -> (q -> r))
((p -> (q -> r)) -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r)))
((p -> q) -> (p -> r))
(((p -> q) -> (p -> r)) -> (q -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r))))
(q -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r)))
((q -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r))) -> ((q -> (p -> q)) -> (q -> (p -> r))))
((q -> (p -> q)) -> (q -> (p -> r)))
(q -> (p -> q))
(q -> (p -> r))
```

Comment: Good answer. However, in regards to your opening sentence of "suppose we rewrite the definition of well-formed formula of M in polish notation," I have a bit of confusion. At the end of your post you state "...Therefore (P -> (Q -> R)) ⊢m (Q -> (P -> R)" can get proven in less than twenty-one steps" which means that you are saying this particular statement _of M_ can be proven _in M_ in less than 21 steps, correct? But wasn't what was shown only that one can correspond with the system M an equivalent system which uses a different yet equivalent definition of well-formed-formulas?

Comment: You then show that the equivalent statement in _this system_ can be proven in less than 21 steps. What I'm having trouble with is that you seemed to imply that the statement _can be proven in M_ in less than 21 steps. Are you saying "Consider a different but equivalent system...here the equivalent statement can be proven in less than 21 steps"  or are you instead saying "let's rewrite the definition of WFFs in M...then yes we can prove the statement _in M_ in less than 21 steps", If it's the latter I'd have to disagree on the grounds that the system being used wouldn't actually be M.

Comment: @Boolean_functions Yes, I'm saying that particular statement can get proven in less then 21 steps.  No, I didn't show that one can correspond the Polish notation system, P, with an equivalent system.  I presumed that I, or someone else, could do so.  To show that you might point out that every well-formed satisfies the definition of a well-formed formula.  Each formula satisfies one of the clauses of such a definition.  If the formula F is variable in M, then the formula F' is a variable in M.  If F is of the type (a->b) in M, then F' is of the type Cab in P.  If ...

Comment: F is of the type $\lnot$a in M, then F' is of the type Na in P.  Since there don't exist any other wffs in M or P, the above implies that every formula F in M has a correspondent F' in P.  The converse direction can get proved also in a similar manner.  Now every formula/wff in any formal proof of either system has a correspondent in the other system.  Thus, to find a short enough proof in M, you only need to take the above proof in P and find every corresponding wff in M.  I'm not saying the later, I'm saying the former.

Comment: You don't even need to look at the steps in the proof above and directly translate them into system M.  Instead, starting with the axioms, you can just follow the steps of the proof analysis to find those formulas that you can use for a similar proof in M.  CCpqCpr can get built up as follows, p, q, Cpq, Cpr, CCpqCpr.  Thus, in M it can get built as p, q, (p -> q), (p -> r), ((p -> q) -> (p-> r)).

Comment: Yes, I understand you didn't show formally that one can correspond the polish notation system with an equivalent system. I should have made clear that I understood you were presuming you or someone else could. The thoughts behind my comments originally stemmed from a thought that ran as follows: let's suppose there was yet another substantially different way to rewrite the definition of well-formed formulas of M.

Comment: Instead of re-writing them in polish notation, we re-wrote them in such-and-such-notation, but let's say that (for whatever reason) it is a complex procedure to translate the statements which used the old definition of WFFs into the statements which use the such-and-such-notation. If the method of translation was inefficient, then this translation would most likely be considered as part of the proof. Point being, wouldn't the process of determining the corresponding WFFs need to be efficient (with "efficient" being defined)?

Comment: For example, if finding every corresponding  such-and-such-notation wff wasn't nearly as efficient/easy as doing so with the Polish-notation wff, but instead was a ridiculosuly complex procedure...but nonetheless once these WFFs were found, the proof was incredibly simple (just a few lines/steps)....then would we still say the statement of M could be proven in just a few lines? Or would the process of determining the equivalent WFF add length to the proof of the statement?  Isn't that the case in computational complexity type problems?

Comment: Also, the symbols for the connectives used in polish notation aren't in the alphabet of M. How then could you say you have done a proof _in M_? (I'm aware my points my be wrong/offtrack, just trying to clarify). Thanks

Comment: I said the above *can* get proven in M.  I didn't say that I had done so.

Comment: Your edit cleared up my confusion. It clicked. Thanks

Comment: It turns out that if we have CaCba, CCaCbcCCabCac as axioms where we allow uniform substitution, and CpCqr as an axiom which doesn't allow uniform substitution, then CqCpr can get proved in exactly 4 steps under the rule of condensed detachment.  The level of such a proof can also equal exactly 4.  All axioms have level 0.  The level of any other formula has level of one greater than the greatest level of the two formulas used to derive it.

Comment: Interesting, but what exactly do you mean by "level"?

Comment: In regards to my confusion before, it was that I was treating the difference of infix and polish notation as implying more of a structural difference of the system.  That is, I was thinking that a proof using polish notation which has n steps doesn't necessarily guarantee the existence of a proof using infix notation in n steps. But that would depend on the axioms, rules of inference, etc that we are working with. In our case, you obviously (now it is) would be working with a structurally similar system and just using Polish notation. Looking back, you made that clear with your 3rd comment

Comment: I had a non-workable definition of level.  This might work "All axioms have level 0. The level of any other deduced formula has level of one greater than the greatest level of the formula(s) used to derive it."  I think the term level first got used in automated reasoning.  I'm using it a somewhat similar manner to how Larry Wos uses it: "Let
the level of an input clause be 0, and the level of a deduced
clause be one greater than the maximum of the
levels of its parents." http://www.automatedreasoning.net/docs_and_pdfs/subformula%20strategy%20backward.pdf  See edit for example.

Answer (score 2):

> $$P \implies Q \implies R \vdash_M Q \implies P \implies R \tag{1}$$

A proof of this can be constructed using typed lambda calculus.

Assuming a lambda expression $A$ exists of type $P \to Q \to R$.  Then the following lambda expression:

$$\lambda ~ b~c~.~A~c~b$$

has type $Q \to P \to R$, given that $b$ has type $Q$ and $c$ has type $P$.  Reducing this expression to combinatory logic, gives:

$$\lambda ~ b~c~.~A~c~b \quad \equiv \quad S (K (S A)) K$$

The above combinatory expression has $4$ instances of function application, $4$ instances of combinators, and there is the assumption of $A$ itself, so there is a proof of (1) using only $9$ steps.

---

Given the following types:

- $A ~:~ P \to Q \to R$
- $b ~:~ Q$
- $c ~:~ P$

and distinguishing the combinators as $S_2 (K_2 (S_1 A)) K_1$ , the types of $K_1$, $K_2$, $S_1$, and $S_2$ work out as:

- $S_1 ~:~ (P \to Q \to R) \to (P \to Q) \to P \to R $
- $K_1 ~:~ Q \to P \to Q$
- $S_2 ~:~ (Q \to (P \to Q) \to P \to R) \to (Q \to P \to Q) \to Q \to P \to R $
- $K_2 ~:~ ((P \to Q) \to P \to R) \to Q \to (P \to Q) \to P \to R$

And the proof looks like:

$$\begin{array} {lll}
(1) & P \implies Q \implies R                                       & \text{Given}  \\
(2) & (P \implies Q \implies R) \implies (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R                   & \text{Ax 2}, a = P, b = Q, c = R \\
(3) & Q \implies P \implies Q                                       & \text{Ax 1}, a = Q, b = Q \\
(4) & (Q \implies (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R) \implies (Q \implies P \implies Q) \implies Q \implies P \implies R & \text{Ax 2}, a = Q, b = P \implies Q, c = P \implies R \\
(5) & ((P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R) \implies Q \implies (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R   & \text{Ax 1}, a = (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R, b = Q \\
(6) & (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R                                                              & \text{Modus Ponens}, (1), (2) \\
(7) & Q \implies (P \implies Q) \implies P \implies R                                                    & \text{Modus Ponens}, (6), (5) \\
(8) & (Q \implies P \implies Q) \implies Q \implies P \implies R                                  & \text{Modus Ponens}, (7), (4) \\
(9) & Q \implies P \implies R                                                                     & \text{Modus Ponens}, (3), (8) \\
\end{array}$$

---

The tedious nature of constructing this proof demonstrates what Smith was writing in his essay.  Hilbert's axiom system is not something you want to use in practice, it's purpose is moreso to demonstrate that logic is possible.  Later work by Gentzen was motivated more by making the logic useful.

Comment: "The above combinatory expression has 4 instances of function application, 4 instances of combinators, and there is the assumption of A itself, so there is a proof of (1) using only 9 steps."  I'm really not very well acquainted with combinatory logic.  But, I've read that there exists a correspondence with condensed detachment.  Please correct any errors I make.  Suppose we had the following combinator L: CCpqCCqrCpr.  (LL)(LL) is a theorem.  We have 4 instances of the combinator L.  3 instances of function application. So, a 7 step substitution and detachment proof exists...

Comment: And that may well hold.  But, a 6 step substitution and detachment proof exists of the result CCpCqrCCsqCpCsr.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm not sure what you are trying to establish.  With lambda calculus / combinatory logic (they are 2 different ways of writing the same thing) , the expressions are proofs, and the types associated with the expressions are theorems.  For example, if the type of $A$ is $x \to y$, and the type of $B$ is $x$, then the type of $AB$ is $y$, and $AB$ is a proof of the theorem $y$ given the premises (the types of $A$ and $B$).  An example of a lambda expression with the type of $L$ would be $\lambda ~ x ~ y ~ . ~ (\lambda ~ z ~ . y ~ x ~ z)$

Comment: What do you mean by lambda expression?  If lambda expression means the same as what Wikipedia calls a lamdba term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus, then you didn't provide an example of a lambda expression.   If lambda expression means lambda term, what you provided in your last sentence doesn't satisfy the definition of a lambda expression.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood $\lambda~x~y~.~z$ is a common abbreviation for $\lambda ~x~.~\lambda ~y~.~z$, it's called currying, the principle is that a $n$-arity function is effectively the same thing as a $1$-arity function that returns an $n-1$-arity function.  I recommend learning lambda calculus, it is the basis of all constructive logic.  There was a  pivotal point in history where the lambda expressions evolved from being used as theorems into being used as proofs.  So when you study it, things like church encoding etc are all pre -pivot, and things like type theory are all post pivot.

Comment: You said a proof looks like, and printed a bunch of right-associated strings.  A formal proof consists of a single wff or a sequence of multiple wffs, under certain conditions.  If a single string in a sequence is not a wff, that sequence is not a formal proof.  Can you write a comprehensive definition of wffs for Smith's language such that in the statement of the problem (1) or in steps (1) through (9) all of the strings in the proof sequence become wffs?  If not, then the above could use an edit, at the very least in the statement of the problem (1) and in steps (1) through (9).